# Why does Ruby benchmark have this method taking 2 seconds but it crashes in production console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a method in a Rails 4.2 app on Heroku that is running an SQL statement in ActiveAdmin to fetch a list of 1 million plus billing records.

```
    def some_method
      BillingRecord.select(<<-SQL.sub(/\n$/, '')
billing_records.first_name as name,
billing_records.email as email
   #some more sql with joins
SQL
  )
```

When I do a benchmark on it via Ruby's benchmark library in the rails production console, I get it taking around 2.1 seconds as follows:

```
               user     system      total        real
study_run:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.002124)
```

If I try to run *some_method* in the rails production console, the console just crashes.  So how is it that Ruby benchmark is claiming 2.1 seconds but when I run it in the console I get a crash?  If it's crashing I would think that the *real* measured time is much higher than 2.1 seconds.

EDIT: code I used to benchmark:

```
Benchmark.bm(10) do |r|
  r.report("study_run:") { some_method }
end
```

Comment: That's not 2.1 seconds but rather 2.1 milliseconds. I think there might be something wrong with your benchmark or it is not retrieving the same number of records as production because 2.1 milliseconds to retrieve 1M+ rows would be lightning speed.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to understand...

Comment: What does your benchmark look like?

Comment: @FrederickCheung, not sure I understand, the benchmark output is above in "first_run"...or do you mean something else?

Comment: I mean what is the code that you ran to produce that output

Comment: @FrederickCheung - added Benchmark code in an edit

Answer (score 1):

Your method generates an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, which is basically an object representing a query. Creating a relation doesn't execute it: your benchmark is just measuring the time it takes to create this query object, which is naturally only going to take a small amount of time.

When you run this method from the rails console, it's still very quick, however the console needs to display the result to you so it calls  `inspect` on the method return value. This in turn causes the relation to actually execute the query which is naturally going to be slower than just generating the query.